# submit onChange using pretty url's

Tags: php, jquery

i've already opened a question for this problem, but it was very bad formulated and because of that i did not get a good response.... so heres another try... hope it's ok

---

i have a form with a selected tag and some options inside

```
<form>
  <select>
     <option selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="1" data-seourl="food-intake">Food intake</option>
     <option value="2" data-seourl="homemade-cake">Homemade cake</option>
     <option value="3" data-seourl="good-fruits">Good fruits</option>
     <option value="4" data-seourl="apple-type">Apple type</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When i select an option (onchange) i want to submit a friendly url to the server that ressembles this:

```
http://www.mywebsite/kitchen/food-intake.1
http://www.mywebsite/kitchen/homenade-cake.2
...
```

instead of sending the default:

```
http://mywebsite/kitchen/?category=1
http://mywebsite/kitchen/?category=2
```

I know how to use mod_rewrite, so that's not a problem. I need to understand how to submit a friendly url instead of the default?

Is javascript (jQuery in this case) the only solution or is there a native solution?

Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do in jQuery.  Which do you prefer?

Comment: There is no "native" option but using JavaScript (for example with jQuery) to manipulate the URL where the browser has to go to.

Comment: I'd vote for jQuery too, it would be cleaner and allow you to build the URL dynamically by using the route as part of the value of the select box.  That'd get you to about 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function()
{
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if ($option.length)
    {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite/kitchen/'+
                               $option.attr('data-seourl')+'.'+
                               $option.attr('value');
    }
});
```

Note: It's not technically a `<form>` submit, but that really all you can reasonably do since the form is going to try to append the query string you don't want. Both methods produce a HTTP GET request, though.

Comment: If the page is allowed to change/reload :)

Comment: Well, that's really the only sane way to "submit" the form without it tacking on the query string. :)

Comment: tried this one and seems to do the job. Works ok on chrome, firefox and, yes, also with IE 9!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jimp's answer, you could use jQuery's AJAX functions:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var url = 'http://www.mywebsite/kitchen/'
        + $option.attr('data-seourl') 
        + '.' 
        + $option.attr('value');
    if ($option.length) {
        console.log("Sending this data via POST request: ", $("form").serialize());
        $.post(url, $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
            console.log("POST request got this response back:", data);
        });
    }
});
```

See also:

- [Basic jQuery AJAX tutorial/example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)
- [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)